# Constructor logic to throw Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, class, constructor

I have a class called `Ship` which should take the physical dimensions `weight`, `height`, and `name` to its constructor. I got a customized `Exception` too that should be thrown when a user tries to instantiate a `Ship` object with illegal parameters...
The user cant enter `0` for `weight` and `height` and won't also try to enter an empty name for the `name` of the ship

```
class Ship {

   private double weight;
   private int height;
   private String name;

   public Ship(int w, int h, String name) {
      // I am not sure if object instance check logic should go here
      // but it should throw this custom exception class defined
   }
}

class CustomIllegalArgumentException extends Exception {

   public CustomIllegalArgumentException(String r) {
      super(r);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please learn to properly indent, and space your code.

Comment: Am not sure if thats possible but i will try

Comment: Learning how to do so is indeed possible. What do you mean?

Comment: I can 100% confirm that it is possible to format the code in your question properly.

Comment: Okay guys, editing the question to show that constructor is child to class

Comment: @Doga Oruc, you happy now?

Comment: @CodeTiger Yes, thank you very much, kind sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your constructor doesn't like the parameters it gets, it can throw the said exception.

```
public Ship(int w, int h, String name) throws CustomIllegalArgumentException{
   if (w <= 0 || h <= 0) {
      throw new CustomIllegalArgumentException("Invalid ship size!");
   }
   if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
      throw new CustomIllegalArgumentException("Give your ship a name!");
   }
   // rest of your logic.
}
```

Comment: Testing your code, will accept answer if it yields positive results

Comment: Hey i passed a null String as an argument ad program didnt throw an illegal name exception....```...=new Ship(9,8,"")```Can you rectify accordingly

Comment: That is not a `null`. It is an empty `String`. You probably pasted it wrong. See this image: https://imgur.com/a/OllJriw (I would edit my answer and put the image there but for some reason, I can't edit my answer???)

Comment: Okay can you edit to make it throw exception for an empty String please?

Comment: Changed it to `if (name == null || name.length() == 0||name.isEmpty())`, works now thanks for that image